# how to activityindicator react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i have a login setup that Works with my api i need to put an activityindicator for when it is loading, i am using react hooks so there is no much  info about it, i know that i have to set it true before the fetching and when it fininsh set it false again, but i cant declare the activityindicator in the same js as my file that fetch the api

here is my login form component called AuthForm

```
 export default function AuthForm  ({ errorMessage, onSubmit }) {

  const [vCellphone, setvCellphone] = useState('');
  const [vPassword, setvPassword] = useState('');
  const [secureTextEntry, setSecureTextEntry] = useState(true);

  onPassPress = () => {
    setSecureTextEntry(!secureTextEntry);
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    const { value, name } = e.target;
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image style={styles.logo} source={require('../assets/Logotipo-All.png')} />
      <Text style={styles.textIniciar}>Iniciar sesión</Text>
      <Text style={styles.textIniciar}></Text>
      <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
        <TextInput style={styles.inputs}
          placeholder="Teléfono"
          underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
          onChangeText={newvCellphone => setvCellphone(newvCellphone)}
          keyboardType={'numeric'}
          value={vCellphone}
          autoCorrect={false}
          autoCompleteType = "off"
          required
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
        <TextInput style={styles.inputs}
          placeholder="Contraseña"
          secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry} 
          underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
          onChangeText={newvPassword => setvPassword(newvPassword)}
          value={vPassword}
          autoCorrect={false}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity  onPress={this.onPassPress}>
          <Image style={styles.inputIcon} source={require('../assets/Visualización.png')}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

      <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.buttonContainer, styles.loginButton]}  
        onPress={() => onSubmit({ vCellphone, vPassword })}>
        <Text style={styles.loginText}>INGRESAR</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>

  );
};
```

this is my api call code called AuthContext

```
  const login  = dispatch => async ({ vCellphone, vPassword }) => {
    const response = await ForceApi.post('/LoginController.php', { vCellphone, vPassword });
    const Validar = response.data.error;
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('id', response.data.id);
    dispatch({ type: 'login', payload: response.data.id});
    if(Validar == false ){
    navigate('Panel');
    } 
};
export const {Provider, Context} = createDataContext(
    authReducer,
    { login, logout, clearErrorMessage, tryLocalSignin, guardar,},
    {id:null, vSolicitudeId:null,errorMessage: ''}, []
);
```

this is the view that calls AuthForm

```
    import { Context } from '../context/AuthContext';
import AuthForm from '../components/AuthForm';
import { NavigationEvents } from 'react-navigation';


const IniciarSesion = () => {
  const { state, login, clearErrorMessage} = useContext(Context);
  onPassPress = () => {
    this.setState({
      secureTextEntry: !this.state.secureTextEntry
    });
  }
  return (

    <View style={styles.container}>
      <NavigationEvents
        onWillBlur = {clearErrorMessage}
      />
      <AuthForm 
        errorMessage = {state.errorMessage}
        onSubmit = {login}
      /> 
    </View>
  );
};
```

any help would be apreciated

Comment: Problem solved ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 'isLoading' state in your component and set it true before form submit and later you can set isLoading to false once you get response.

on `onSubmit`, you can pass success callback, e.g.

```
onPress={() => {
  this.setState({
    isLoading: true,
  });

  onSubmit({
    vCellphone,
    vPassword,
    successCB: () => {
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
      });
    },
  });
}}
```

Then in login logic call **success callback** on success, e.g.

```
const login = dispatch => async ({ vCellphone, vPassword, successCB }) => {
  // your code
  if(successLogin) {
    successCB()
  }
  // navigate
};
```

**NOTE:** You can also use redux to maintain your `isLoading` state.

Answer (score 1):

```
export default function name(){
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            setIsLoading(false);
        }, 5000);
    }, []);

    if(isLoading){
        return(
            <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                <ActivityIndicator size="large"/>
            </View>
        );
    }

    return(
    ...your code...
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** You need to conditionally render the ActivityIndicator.

You probably want to create a 'loading' state variable in your component, e.g.

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
```

Then in your render method, **conditionally** render the ActivityIndicator

```
  return loading ? (
<View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
  <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
</View>
) : (<YourComponent />);
```

where **YourComponent** is the component to be shown when it is not loading.

Currently the `loading` state is default initialised to true, so ActivityIndicator will always show loading. In your useEffect hook, you should `setLoading` to false after calling APIs or otherwise load data. Alternatively, you can set default initialise to false, so YourComponent is shown instead.

More information at [react native website](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/activityindicator).

Comment: but how do i know when it stops loading? i cant put the hook in the context.js

Comment: *You* have to make it stop loading with `setLoading(false)`, when you want it to stop loading. For example, if you're loading information from a fetch request, in the callback, call `setLoading(false)`. This will remove the ActivityIndicator only after the response is returned.